# Need to rewrite url in dynamic web project jsp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a dynamic web project with maven, using technology as jquery, jsp pages and servlets. I have an example url in my application below:

```
www.mydomain.com/JohnSmith.html
```

(Above name "JohnSmith" is parametric, anybody can save any HTML with new name, it can be "SueBrown", "DemiMoore" etc. )

When user click to photos link in JohnSmith.html, I want to make URL like below:

```
www.mydomain.com/JohnSmith/photos/
```

And when user click to any photo in listed photos page, I want to make URL like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/JohnSmith/photos/545425 (--> id of image)
```

Which structure should I use? My project is running on *Linux, Apache tomcat 7, and Apache web server 2.4*. I looked into "Rewrite Cond" and "Rewrite Rule" on web server configuration, but it is very complex, I couldn't succeed to apply this scenario.

Comment: Don't use url rewriting. You normally have an MVC framework to handle the requests which has a front controller. WIth that you can map your urls to anything you want. Have a look at [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), that can do this for you.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I looked into link you sent and assume that it will more useful for us, I will do some examples to test it.